# Given start & end dates without year, where can I find average daily high & low temperatures for a given city?

Tags: data-request, weather, city

I'm looking for a simple site that offers daily high & low temperature averages for a given city.  For example, I'd like to get the average high & low temperatures by day for Cabo San Lucas from Oct 1 through Apr 30.

Ideally, it would be via a simple HTTP GET request, like: `GET http://somewhere?city=Cabo+San+Lucas&start=0110&end=3004` and return data in JSON or CSV format, like

`date,hi,lo
0110,83,74
0210,83,73
0310,82,73
...
3112,78,67
0101,78,67
0102,77,66
...
2904,80,72
3004,80,72`

It wouldn't matter which units are given (my example is in degrees Farenheit, but any unit would do).  It would be very similar to http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/ZipWeather.asp, except that it should support international cities and not require postal code.  Ambiguous city names should result in a `400` or similar.

Anyone know of such a site?

Comment: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ may or may not have what you want.